# How to add friction to Unity HingeJoint?

Tags: unity, physics, joints, physx

I attach a rigidbody to a HingeJoint in Unity.

It's attached no at the the center of an anchor of a joint.

To stop it from falling I set `Use Motor = true`, `Target Velocity = 0` and apply some force to the motor.

However, this does not help, see video:

http://g.recordit.co/JJ0cmfT1Mb.gif

Here is the sample project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QGeF3SuAgTNnozX05wTVJGZHc

Screen from sample project to reproduce the issue (there is no code):
[image]

How can I apply a friction to a joint to stop rigidbody from moving?

Setting spring with damper or applying a limit is not an option for me, because I need to rotate the rigidbody correctly when I apply enough torque (force) to a motor.
If I switch damper/limit on and off, the rigidbody will move faster when it is rotated in a direction of falling and slower when it is rotated in opposite direction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this for not containing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We can't accept off-site sample projects, because otherwise the question won't be a future-proof reference.

Comment: Fortunately, @doppelgreener, the HingeJoint is a built-in component, so this question does contain enough information to reproduce the issue in Unity even without seeing OP's code or project files.